# jQuery Mobile - unbinding hover from links

Tags: jquery-mobile

I'm working with jQuery Mobile, trying to unbind hover from links – long story short, [this](http://jsfiddle.net/resedasue/7H8Dx/1/)  is an abbreviated form of what I’m trying.

When the link is hovered over the ui-btn-up class for that link is removed and ui-btn-hover is added (i.e. the styling is not changed via the hover pseudo class in css, instead a new class is added programmatically, if that’s the right way of putting it). Anyway, that's what I don't want to occur - would rather the styling stay the same.  Have found a few questions posted here that seemed to hover close to this issue (see what I did there?), but trying the suggestions hasn’t worked.  Would appreciate any advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this, but this is more a workaround/hack

```
$('li').bind('mouseover', function(){
   return false;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7H8Dx/4/

Comment: Thanks so much - works perfectly!  Going to bother me if I can't get that unbind to work but really glad to have a workaround.

Comment: Yes, i'm still figuring out where/when the class ui-btn-hover is toggled, haven't found it yet

Comment: Looks like it's jQuery Mobile's virtual mouse event vmouseover.  I can unbind it at document level but that seems a bit overkill, though tempting (don't really need hover for mobile app). Will just bind to it per your answer.  Thx again.